# Serial write a list of bytes

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

In Python 2.x I can Serial port write a list of bytes like this:

```
numbers=[0x40,0x00,0x99,0x54,0x78,0x13]
for x in numbers:        
    ser.write(x)
```

Now I'm converting to Python 3.8.6 it doesn't work.  From what I read, in Python 3 all serial writes must be strings or "byte literals".  What is the best way to convert my list of numbers into "byte literals" that I can send out the serial port?  I don't really understand what "byte literal" means...

Comment: you can create a byte list like this `byte_list = [bytes(x) for x in numbers]` if I am not mistaken

Comment: @BijayRegmi You are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
numbers=[0x40,0x00,0x99,0x54,0x78,0x13]
numbers=bytes(numbers)    
ser.write(numbers)
```

What confused me was when I tried testing the bytes() operation on a single number, that creates a byte literal string filled with zeros. But if you do the bytes() operation on a list, it converts the list to a byte literal string.